# Merge two list in C# based on a condition

Tags: c#, list, merge

I have two lists based on the class

```
public class test
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Int32 quantity { get; set; }
}

List1 
{"A", 1}
{"B", 2}
{"C", 3}

List2
{"A", 1}
{"B", 4}
{"D", 5}
```

The merged list needs to include all the items from both the list and if the same id occurs in both the lists, then the quantity should be compared and the one with greater quantity should be selected.
The merged list needs to be

```
Merged list
{"A", 1}
{"B", 4}
{"C", 3}
{"D", 5}
```

order of the items in the list is not important.

How to implement this merge.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is stumping you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
var query = list1.Concat(list2)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.id)
                 .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.quantity).First())
                 .ToList();
```

It's not nice, but it would work. (This approach avoids creating a *new* instance of test as lc.'s answer does. I don't know whether that's important to you, but I can see it being important in some scenarios.)

It does assume that if an ID occurs more than once in either of the lists, that you still only want it to be returned once in the result.

Alternatively, using `MaxBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var query = list1.Concat(list2)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.id)
                 .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.quantity))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Could replace that pesky `.OrderByDescending(x=>x.quantity).First()` with `.Max(x=>x.quantity)`.

Comment: @Blindy: Not while keeping the *existing* objects. `Max` would return the quantity, not the object with the largest quantity.

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming "ID" should always be unique:

```
var list = (from l in List1.Concat(List2)
           group l by l.id into g
           select new test() {id = g.Key, quantity = g.Max(x=>x.quantity)})
           .ToList();
```